# REGEXP_REPLACE to replace specific duplicated characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling with the usage of REGEXP_REPLACE. Currently I'm trying to work on a string similar to the following one:

```
ABC|||CDE|||||DEF||||||556|||.|.|
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have only one pipe per group. Hence the objective string is:

```
ABC|CDE|DEF|556|.|.|
```

Can this be done using REGEXP_REPLACE or a similar function? How?
Notice I won't have control of the position of the characters in the string, & that there won't be a pattern (e.g. "every five characters there are pipes"). I just need to remove immediate pipe duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE(value,'(\|)+','|')` . For example

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC|||CDE|||||DEF|||||||556||||.|.|','(\|)+','|') newval
FROM dual
```

Comment: You're a life-savior. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**OF COURSE** regular expressions are prettier, but - for amusement, to show that good, old `REPLACE` does the job.

```
SQL> select
  2    replace(
  3      replace(
  4        replace('ABC|||CDE|||||DEF|||||||556||||.|.|',      --> input string
  5                '|',
  6                '|' || chr(9)
  7               ),
  8              chr(9) || '|'
  9             ),
 10             chr(9), '') result
 11  from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
ABC|CDE|DEF|556|.|.|

SQL>
```

Comment: . . . Why `chr(9)`?

Comment: Because I guessed that input string won't have it, @Gordon. Could've been something else, e.g. `#` or ...